# Is there a way to select dynamically created CSS to display somewhere else?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a dynamically created table of contents that is numbered using css. The numbering is inserted using ::before as seen in the picture below before the `a` tags.

```
<div class="toc-list-item toc-level-1 show-css-numbering" style="font-weight: bold;">
<a class="entry-text contents" id="TOCEntry_1_ID" href="#TOCEntry1ID">Integrated Wealth Planning</a>
</div>
```

I would like to know if there is a way I can select this specific number and prepend it to the corresponding heading from the table of contents.

I tried this:

```
$heading.prepend("<span class='heading-number'>{0})&nbsp;</span>".format($(".entry-text::before")));
```

But it doesn't even look like it would work and it only ends up prepending `{0})`. Does anyone have any ideas about how I could go about selecting the number? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
My CSS:

```
#inject-toc-here {
            counter-reset: heading;
        }

        .show-css-numbering.toc-level-1:before {
            content: counter(heading)") ";
            counter-increment: heading;
        }

        .show-css-numbering.toc-level-1 {
            counter-reset: subheadingLVL2;
        }

        .show-css-numbering.toc-level-2:before {
            content: counter(heading)"." counter(subheadingLVL2)") ";
            counter-increment: subheadingLVL2;
        }

        .show-css-numbering.toc-level-2 {
            counter-reset: subheadingLVL3;
        }

        .show-css-numbering.toc-level-3:before {
            content: counter(heading)"." counter(subheadingLVL2)"." counter(subheadingLVL3)") ";
            counter-increment: subheadingLVL3;
        }

        .show-css-numbering.toc-level-3 {
            counter-reset: subheadingLVL4;
        }

        .show-css-numbering.toc-level-4:before {
            content: counter(heading)"." counter(subheadingLVL2)"." counter(subheadingLVL3)"." counter(subheadingLVL4)") ";
            counter-increment: subheadingLVL4;
        }

        .show-css-numbering.toc-level-4 {
            counter-reset: subheadingLVL5;
        }

        .show-css-numbering.toc-level-5:before {
            content: counter(heading)"." counter(subheadingLVL2)"." counter(subheadingLVL3)"." counter(subheadingLVL4)"." counter(subheadingLVL5)") ";
            counter-increment: subheadingLVL5;
        }

        .show-css-numbering.toc-level-5 {
            counter-reset: subheadingLVL6;
        }

        .show-css-numbering.toc-level-6:before {
            content: counter(heading)"." counter(subheadingLVL2)"." counter(subheadingLVL3)"." counter(subheadingLVL4)"." counter(subheadingLVL5)"." counter(subheadingLVL6)") ";
            counter-increment: subheadingLVL6;
        }
```

It looks like a lot because of the amount of subheadings possible.

Comment: Pseudo elements are not accessible from jQuery selectors. You'd need to use plain JS for this, something like `window.getComputedStyle(yourElement, ':before').getPropertyValue('content');` Note that `yourElement` here is an Element object, not a jQuery object.

Comment: Also note that you should post the actual HTML in the question as text, not an image. It makes it needlessly difficult to recreate your code to test.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan its dynamically created so I can only post result. I also cannot post all my heading HTML unfortunately because its too long.

Comment: `its dynamically created so I can only post result` you can't copy and paste from the console you've taken a screenshot of? ;)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan oh yes I can haha, sorry... I will edit now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pseudo elements are not accessible from jQuery selectors. You'd need to use plain JS for this, using `getComputedStyle()`. Something like this:

```js
var $heading = $('#heading');

var beforeContent = window.getComputedStyle($('.toc-list-item')[0], ':before').getPropertyValue('content').replace(/"/g, '');
$heading.prepend(`<span class="heading-number">${beforeContent}&nbsp;</span>`);
```

```css
.toc-list-item {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.toc-list-item::before {
  content: '123';
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 210px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toc-list-item toc-level-1 show-css-numbering">
  <a class="entry-text contents" id="TOCEntry_1_ID" href="#TOCEntry1ID">Integrated Wealth Planning</a>
</div>

<div id="heading">&lt; content value</div>
```

Also note you have a typo, there's no 'r in 'Integrated'.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help and patience!

Comment: how would I select it though if there is no `content`?

Comment: If there's no content, then surely there's nothing displayed..? Unless I'm misunderstanding the requirements.

Comment: Sorry I meant to clarify after I commented. My content is css counters. So now it is just displaying `counter(heading) )`. I will update my question with my css.

Comment: I think you're stuck in that case. `getComputedStyle` reads the literal string value of the `content` rule, it doesn't get the interpreted value. You may be able to do something using the `index` of the elements, but that entirely depends on how your HTML is structured and when/how you increment the values. I'd suggest starting a new question for that if you want to go down that path.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer previously though. It helped me get going in the right direction.

Comment: No problem, glad to help